# Git conflict not showing my committed changes

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I have two branches (`master` and `abc`)

I have added some code in `abc` and committed the abc.
I pulled `origin/master` and now my `abc` is behind a few commits.

When I rebase or merge `abc` with `master`, in conflict resolver; it does not show the changes in the conflict file that I committed.
Why?

Comment: What are the conflicts? Maybe there are none. What is the "conflict resolver"? Which commands did you run? Can you share the repository?

Answer (score 3):

Try this sequence:

```
git switch abc
# work and commit
git switch master
git pull
git switch abc
git rebase master
```

If there are any files which have changed *both* on `origin/master` and on local `abc` branch, the `git rebase` command will ask you for merge conflict resolution.
But if the modified files in `abc` were not modified in `origin/master`, the rebase would complete automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Hi conflict arises when a file present in two branches with modified content,
In your case , consider a file `sample.txt` is present in `master` and `abc`
and content of the file is not same and if you try to `merge`.
The conflicts can be merged in `github` web or using  `git bash`